# SQL count the number of mentions

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have such table

```
id | numbers
1  | 3,4,5
2  | 1,7,3
3  | 2,8,4,5
4  | 6,2,8
```

I need to count what numbers are most common.
PostgreSQL. Numbers into rows are in such format: '{1, 2, 3}'

So I expect smth like this:

```
numbers | counter
      1 | 1
      2 | 2
      3 | 2
      4 | 2
      5 | 2
      6 | 1
      7 | 1
      8 | 2
```

Comment: You said numbers are like `3,4,5` and you said numbers are like `'{1, 2, 3}'` - which is it? is it actually JSON in the column? (which would be like '[1, 2, 3]')

Comment: What data type is the column `numbers`?

Comment: Please post the schema of your table. Thank you

Comment: data type here is _int4

Answer (score 1):

You can split the values and aggregate:

```
select n, count(*)
from t cross join lateral
     regexp_split_to_table(t.numbers, ',') n
group by n
order by n;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=53c041c5cc16cff7fc40bf10bb33ab0c) is a db<>fiddle.

Then, you should fix your data model.  Do not store lists of numbers.  Here are some reasons:

- Numbers should be stored as *numbers* not strings.
- SQL has pretty lousy string processing capabilities.
- Postgres has great methods for storing lists, including *tables* and *arrays*.
- If these are foreign keys, the foreign key relationship should be properly declared.